# Need to move every 5000 files to new folder using batch script

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I have a folder with >10000000 files need to move them to individual folder of 5000 each. Using batch script how do i move them to individual folders?

Comment: How should the folders be named? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
while true; do
    ls | head -5000 > ../files
    if [ ! -s ../files ]; then
       break
    fi
    (( i++ )) # Boomer here but feeling younger every day thanks to KamilCuk.
    mkdir ../dir$i # I know. No error checking here.
    while read filename; do
       mv "$filename" ../dir$i # No error checking here either.
    done < ../files
done
```

This script becomes an infinite loop if `mkdir` or `mv` fail repeatedly. You also have to be careful where you store the temporary file `files` and where you make your destination directories; otherwise the next `ls` has to avoid recognizing the previous loop iteration's output directory.

The script also has trouble if a file's name contains a newline character (unlikely but simple to accomplish). And if you have that use case, then, again, this script will enter an infinite loop since the `mv` command will fail because the `read` would fail to correctly read that filename.

Comment: [Do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). `Boomer here` :) [bash hackers wiki Obsolete and deprecated syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). `while [ 1 ]`, just `while :` or `while true`. The `[ 1 ]` is strange, it checks if the string `1` has nonzero length.

Comment: @KamilCuk It would be more than convenient if `mv` could read a list of files one line at a time. Then the character escaping problem would probably be moot.